# getting result from $res = $db->select($query); in array

Tags: php

After getting result from this query :

```
$res = $db->select($query);
```

in array. How can I convert the data from array into some other state and if the database have a much data so how can I make a for each loop to get the whole database data. Please briefly guide me.

Comment: There are dozen of guides on how to use php with a database out there, you just need to google it, it's not what SO is for, I'd strongly recommend you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: if you can put in some code block you have tried doing, may be we can help  out something, without that, its not possible to help!

Answer (score 0):

There is not any code, just suppose that. there is some mysql query in $query and after execution we got many data which is more two columns with select query not count query. Now, the data is coming in an array. firstly I want to convert this getting array into simple text then want to start a foreach loop to run the query on multiple time.